# Custom Bootstrap 5 Build using NPM and Vscode

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I have been using Bootstrap 3.4.1 for many years, and am working on moving it to Bootstrap 5.3.

Back in [Version 3.4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/) it was possible to customise your download, which would result in a smaller download when users visit your website (sorry for non-technical speak).

However I am struggling to work out how to do similar in version 5.3.

I am using VSCode and have installed Node.js on my laptop, and  have worked through the [Bootstrap 5 Crash Course Tutorial #19 - Customizing Bootstrap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCX3QVl_PiI) tutorial.

That was useful in as much as it helped provide steps to override some default styles and to add some of your own custom styles - e.g. by adding your own `scss` file:

```
// custom variables
$primary: #c29938;
$light: pink;

// import the functions & variables
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions';
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables';

$custom-theme-colors: (
    "altlight": #f2ebfa,
    "altdark": #522192
);

$theme-colors: map-merge($custom-theme-colors, $theme-colors);

// import bootstrap
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

However, I am struggling to find any guidance about how I would be able to compile my own bootstrap file that excluded bootstrap components I don't want to use, such as:

- accordion
- carousel
- modal
- dropdown

etc. etc.

Is it possible to do this using the Vscode / NPM setup I have installed, and using SCSS files, or do I need to learn about other routes using LESS and Gulp and all sorts of other things?

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you able to [import just the components you need](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/optimize/#lean-sass-imports)?

Comment: Per BS documentation "When using Sass in your asset pipeline, make sure you optimize Bootstrap by only `@import`ing the components you need." https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/optimize/